# How do i change the pointer of a variable pass into a function

Tags: java, reference

Can some one tell me how i would achieve the following. Java is not my strong point and after trying to search i keep getting pages on javas always pass by reference.

```
void edit(int[] a){
    a = new String[]{"q","r","s","t","u"};
}

int[] x = new int[]{"a","b","c"};
edit(x);
System.out.println(x); // ["q","r","s","t","u"]
```

Im trying to achieve the above so that i can change the pointer of x after i've passed it into a function.

### Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is **purely** pass-by-value. You cannot do anything inside a method that changes the value of a variable used as an argument to the method. It simply isn't possible in Java.

In your example, you *can* change the *content* of the array, you just can't change what array `x` is referring to. You'd do that like this:

```
void edit(int[] a) {
   a[0] = 1;
   a[1] = 2;
   a[2] = 3;
}
```

Note the distinction here: You can change the *content* of the array `x` refers to, but you can't change `x` from within `edit`. So for example, you can't change the length of the array, because the only way to do that is to create a new array and point `x` at it, and you can't do that within `edit`.

Other options:

- Have `edit` return a new array, then assign that to `x`.
- Use `List`, so you can change how many elements there are.
- Create a class with mutable properties and pass an instance of that class in.

Comment: Ok bad example, i actually need to do the above with String[]. I also need to resize the array (it was a very bad exmaple)

Comment: @kizzie33: Same answer.

Comment: +1 - I was just about to post an answer regarding changing the content of the array, but you edited your answer!:)

Comment: kizzie33 could also extend the integer pointer class so that he includes this as a method of that class and put a (temporrary array) as a return value. I assume this could work

Comment: The issue is its a university assignment. And it said that i need to edit the contents but the function must not return anything...Thank you, i'll go back to him and ask him to clarify.

Comment: @kizzie33: See above, you **can** do that. You can change the *content* of the array, you just can't change what array `x` refers to.

Comment: Like you just wrote, you need to edit *the contents* and T.J. provided you with a way to do it. Just change the contents of the elements of the array, not the pointer to the beginning of the array.

Comment: How do you resize an array in in Java without remaking it ? Plus it must be a native array.

Comment: @kizzie33: Again, see above: *"So for example, you can't change the length of the array, because the only way to do that is to create a new array"* You cannot.